# Как определить требования к серверу для бота

Tags: python, база-данных, бот

Написал бота, нужно выбрать хостинг. Буду брать в аренду VPS, но не знаю, сколько необходимо ядер, оперативной памяти и прочего. Ботом будут пользоваться не более 100 человек, но есть постоянная работа с БД. Как быть?

Comment: Выбрать самый дешёвый. Если вдруг не хватит - переехать на более дорогой.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, верно, однако. Попробую )

Comment: Запустить локально, имитировать нагрузку, похожую на реальную и посмотреть на потребление ресурсов.